# Query JSONB column using joins to filter by subquery referencing outer query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I need to analyze survey data (stored in records) where a question can have a choice of options. My goal is to identify the answers given that were NOT within the range of allowed options for this question. However, my query returns everything (I suspect a subquery) and I don't know how to fix it.

### Schema

The records stores its data in the `data` JSONB column. There, the keys are `question` UIDs, e.g. `uid00000006` has the answer `option1`. `option1` is a choice to select.
(Not all questions need to have a dropdown, so some other value is fine such as 42.)

```
{"uid00000006": {"value": "option1"}, "uid00000008": {"value": 42}}
```

A `question` optionally has a reference to a `optionset` (the dropdown) which has a range of `optionvalues` (the values of the dropdown) , e.g. `option1`, `option2`, `option3` etc.

```
create table record
(
    recordid bigint not null primary key,
    uid varchar(11) unique,
    data jsonb default '{}'::jsonb not null
);


create table question
(
    questionid bigint not null primary key,
    uid varchar(11) not null unique,
    optionsetid bigint 
);

create table optionset
(
    optionsetid bigint not null primary key,
    uid varchar(11) not null unique
);

create table optionvalue
(
    optionvalueid bigint not null primary key,
    uid varchar(11) not null unique,
    code varchar(230) not null,
    optionsetid bigint
);



-- create optionset
INSERT INTO optionset (optionsetid, uid) VALUES (1, 'uid00000001');

-- insert optionvalues into optionset
INSERT INTO optionvalue (optionvalueid, uid, code, optionsetid) VALUES (100, 'uid00000002', 'option1', 1);
INSERT INTO optionvalue (optionvalueid, uid, code, optionsetid) VALUES (101, 'uid00000003', 'option2', 1);
INSERT INTO optionvalue (optionvalueid, uid, code, optionsetid) VALUES (102, 'uid00000004', 'option3', 1);
INSERT INTO optionvalue (optionvalueid, uid, code, optionsetid) VALUES (103, 'uid00000005', 'option4', 1);

-- insert questions
INSERT INTO question (questionid, uid, optionsetid) VALUES (1001, 'uid00000006', 1);
INSERT INTO question (questionid, uid, optionsetid) VALUES (1002, 'uid00000007', 1);
INSERT INTO question (questionid, uid, optionsetid) VALUES (1003, 'uid00000008', NULL);

-- insert records
INSERT INTO record (recordid, uid, data) VALUES (10001, 'uid00000009', '{"uid00000006": {"value": "option1"}, "uid00000008": {"value": 42}}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO record (recordid, uid, data) VALUES (10002, 'uid00000010', '{"uid00000006": {"value": "option2"}}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO record (recordid, uid, data) VALUES (10003, 'uid00000011', '{"uid00000006": {"value": "UNMAPPED"}}'::jsonb);
```

### My query

My drafted query is:

```
SELECT r.uid             AS record_uid,
       key               AS question_uid,
       os.uid            AS optionset_uid,
       value ->> 'value' AS value
FROM record r, JSONB_EACH(r.data)
JOIN question q ON q.uid = key
JOIN optionset os ON q.optionsetid = os.optionsetid
WHERE q.optionsetid IS NOT NULL
AND value::varchar NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM optionvalue WHERE optionsetid = q.optionsetid)
;
```

[**DBFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ZrLQ68DAcSxLVpXiPSQK6/0)

### Problem

The query above returns all records instead only one. In reference to the sample data, the expected result would be to return only the record where the value is `UNMAPPED` (meaning it is the record where an answer was given that is not "valid").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `value::varchar NOT IN` to `value ->> 'value' NOT IN`

```sql
SELECT
  r.uid             AS record_uid,
  key               AS question_uid,
  os.uid            AS optionset_uid,
  value ->> 'value' AS value
FROM
  record r, jsonb_each(r.data)
  JOIN question q ON q.uid = key
  JOIN optionset os ON q.optionsetid = os.optionsetid
WHERE 
 q.optionsetid IS NOT NULL
 AND value ->> 'value' NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM optionvalue WHERE optionsetid = q.optionsetid);
```